# How to create query order by not in JPA Criteria Builder

Tags: jpa, hibernate-criteria

I want to ask, how to make a query order by not in in java, this is the query, thank you:

```
select * from $table_name order by id not in
(select r.transaction_id from $child_table r where r.transaction_id is not null) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getHibernateSession();
CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<PARENT_ENTITY> cr = cb.createQuery(<PARENT_ENTITY>.class);
Root<PARENT_ENTITY> root = cr.from(PARENT_ENTITY.class);
CriteriaQuery<PARENT_ENTITY> cr_child = cb.createQuery(<CHILD_ENTITY>.class);
Root<CHILD_ENTITY> child_root = cr_child.from(CHILD_ENTITY.class);

cr.select(root).where(cb.isNotNull(child_root.get("transaction_id")));
```

Please try to fill the values for entities as per requirement, hope this helps